# TeamCity pending changes are not run

Tags: teamcity

I have got configured TeamCity to execute NUnit tests.

When I run manually it then it is working fine. But somehow it accumulates pending changes and doesn't run test even if I refresh overview page of TeamCity.

I am wondering which setting I have to use so pending changes will run?

Basically I would like to start first pending changes to execute as soon as it appears.

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing your build trigger.  When you edit the project settings, you should see the Build Triggers step (#5).  It's the spot where you need to add the event that tells TeamCity it should kick off a build.  It is generally tied to your source control check-ins/commits.

You probably want to use the `VCS Trigger` to kick off the build.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I just added that trigger but pending # is the same... Have I force somehow TeamCity so it will release the pending #?

Comment: The pending # are the number of changes that TeamCity sees since the last build. You should see it kick off a build after your next check-in/commit.

Comment: You can also receive this problem if you have an error in the trigger settings.  So if you have a trigger defined review it's settings. (For instance I had a trigger watching the wrong vcs root)

Comment: Looks like it also accumulates pending changes if in your VCS trigger you have trigger rules specified. If you specify folder A in trigger rules and change is in folder B build won't be triggered but pending change will appear.

Comment: I had the same problem after I moved build configuration from one project to another. It was enough to update the VCS to fix this problem.