# TeamCity CI build pull requests from BitBucket -> ArcBees/teamcity-plugins

Tags: git, merge, teamcity, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm trying to use the following plug in but for some reason the trigger does not get hit.

https://github.com/ArcBees/teamcity-plugins/wiki/Configuring-Bitbucket-Pull-Requests-Plugin

I think the VCS Root is correct because all pending changes from Pull Requests shows up, the problem is that they only show as `Pending` and never starts to build.

[image]

The settings menu for the trigger does not look like the Wiki description but it is quite similar. For API URL I have tried both `https://bitbucket.org` and `https://api.bitbucket.org`. Other values are checked and correct, the user has access to the repository.

[image]

Version: `TeamCity Enterprise 2017.1.3 (build 46961)`

According to this question it should be trigger related:

[TeamCity pending changes are not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519980/teamcity-pending-changes-are-not-run)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/ArcBees/teamcity-plugins/issues/56) the problem could be solved by updating the base branch to be `master` rather than `ref/heads/master`